# Wifi won't connect to network

Tags: wifi

Why can't I connect to WiFi?
I have a Lumia 535 for a while and was not able to connect to network, a message would indicate network did not respond or phone can not connect.
What I had to due to be able to connect was go to manually configure network and turn off and select ready and since I had removed the network I have to introduce the WiFi password and that's all.

Comment: Which is the os you are using.? What is the actual message you are getting when you try to connect.? What encryption is used in wifi.? Please confirm DHCP is on in your modem settings. Also please check wifi with any other device.